# change validation (html5) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I need a code for change validation of html5 form.
in my `confirm password` i have a `onKeyUp` that when the user change `Confirm password` field, change the background-image, now for complete the code.

**html**:

```
<input class="txtNewPassword" type="password" name="password1" id="txtConfirmPassword" required title="enter password">
```

**and JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});

function checkPasswordMatch() {
var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

if (password != confirmPassword)
{
    $('#txtNewPassword').css("background-image", "url(images/root/invalid.png)");  
    $('#txtConfirmPassword').css("background-image", "url(images/root/invalid.png)");  
}
else
{
    $('#txtNewPassword').css("background-image", "url(images/root/valid.png)");  
    $('#txtConfirmPassword').css("background-image", "url(images/root/valid.png)");  
}
}
```

How can I add the jquery validation to `onKeyUp`?

Comment: it's working fine here:http://jsfiddle.net/6pjqZ/

Comment: you want something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XeMh6/ (i removed background, to show it works)

Comment: i try this codes friend, but it was not the thing i need!
i need a code like {$("#txt").css("background-image",url(images/root/valid.png)");}

Comment: just a single line of code!

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: Typical your validation should toggle a class on the elements, like `invalid`, and leave the actual styling (`background-image`) to your CSS. Right now you're mixing display code and business logic code.